# Upload Image in Create Pin API

Tags: pinterest

While invoking create pin api with uploaded image i got the below exception,

**{"message": "You need to upload an image or provide the 'image_url' parameter", "type": "api"}**

Can anyone tell me how to upload image in Pinterest API and what should be the format of an image?

Comment: can you share curl code here please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1. If the image is already on the web, you can pass in the URL directly as the `image_url` parameter, as shown in the example request on https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/pins/.
2. You can post an image file directly as the `image` param however you would normally post a file in the framework you are using.
3. You can post Base64 encoded image data as the `image_base64` param.